# Apache htaccess rewrite rule to deny external sites access to sub-directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I wish to prevent external websites from accessing a sub-directory of files on my website. I've written a rule and tested using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, but even though it matches as expected in the test with external refererrs, it fails to work on my site.

Specifically links from Google to private files still work and don't redirect to my websites homepage as I'm expecting. I've checked the HTTP headers and the Google referrer is present as expected.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !test.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)my_sub_directory(.*)$ https://test.example.com/? [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule in `/my_sub_directory/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !=test.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://test.example.com/? [R,L]
```